# ionic2 Angular 2 bind checkboxes with a ngFor inside a form

Tags: angular, ionic2

How do I bind a checkerbox with `ngfor` within a form

```
    <ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'contacts'">
        <ion-item *ngFor="#contact of contacts">
            <ion-label> {{contact.name}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox checked="false" [(ngModel)]="newMessage.contact"></ion-checkbox>
            <ion-note item-right>
                {{contact.cell}}
            </ion-note>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Everything gets clicked or the form displays a error

```
if (form.valid) {
    console.log(this.newMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a boolean field in the `contact` object to hold the state of each checkbox, the same way you have a `name` or a `cell`. You could call it `checked` for instance, and it will hold a `true` or `false` value for each contact depending on the state of the respective checkbox.

```
 <ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'contacts'">
        <ion-item *ngFor="#contact of contacts">
            <ion-label> {{contact.name}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox checked="false" [(ngModel)]="contact.checked"></ion-checkbox>
            <ion-note item-right>
                {{contact.cell}}
            </ion-note>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: Wow thanks @manuValdes It totally makes sense now. I could not find it anywhere in the documentation...Good explanation too :)

Answer (score 1):

Had to find out the hard way but you can add a object within a ngModal.I'm guessing but this could also work for radio boxes, hope this will help someone.

```
    <ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'contacts'">
        <ion-item *ngFor="#contact of contacts">
            <ion-label> {{contact.name}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="newMessage[contact.id]"></ion-checkbox>
            <ion-note item-right>
                {{contact.cell}}
            </ion-note>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```